# Invertibility of a map

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that $g\circ f(x) = x$, for all $x \in D(f)$ and $f\circ g(y) = y$ for all $y \in D(g)$. Prove that $g = f^{-1}$! I've an idea that $f$ and $g$ are invertible, so we can directly assume that $g = f^{-1}$, however, my friend doesn't agree to my answer since the value of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ could be either, for instance, $x_1$ or $x_2$.

Comment: This seems to be the definition of the inverse function. It is not clear what the comment about $x_1$ or $x_2$ means.

Comment: You should probably change those to $(g\circ f)(x)$ and $(f\circ g)(y)$. Function application is very high in the order of operations, so $g\circ f(x)$ is likely to be read as $g \circ (f(x))$.

Answer (score 2):

(i) Let $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then, by your first property,  $x_1=g\bigl(f(x_1)\bigr)=g\bigl(f(x_2)\bigr)=x_2$. This shows that $f:\ D_f\to D_g$ is injective.

(ii) Let an arbitrary $y\in D_g$ be given. Putting $g(y)=x$ we know, by your second property, that $x\in D_f$ and that $f(x)=y$. This shows that $f:\ D_f\to D_g$ is surjective.

(iii) So $f:\ D_f\to D_g$ is a bijective map and has a well defined inverse $f^{-1}:\ D_g\to D_f$, which is bijective as well. It is obvious now that in fact $f^{-1}=g$.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is wrong. You are given $ g \circ f(x)=x$. Thus, if we set $g=f^{-1}$ then $f^{-1} \circ f(x) = f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ (no ambiguity here).

Answer (score 1):

Given $f$, the function $f^{-1}$, if it exists, must satisfy the condition that $f \circ f^{-1} (x) = x$ for all $x \in D(f)$, and $f^{-1} \circ f (y) = y$ for all $y \in D(g)$. The function $g$ satisfies these conditions by definition.

Comment: It would help, in the future if you provided the formal definition of "inverse function" provided by your mathematics text.